# Couldn't access values of form after $.POST call?

Tags: jquery, yii

I'm having a form and using the $.POST for posting it to the some url..

From there i couldn't access the form values. I dont know what the error may be??

The form is like

```
<form id="registration-form" >
<input type="hidden" name="Profile[fb_uid]" value='1232323'></input>"
<select name="Profile[feet]" id="feet">
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
</select>
<a class="btnLgBlueGrad" href="#" name="closeModal" id="profileSubmit">Start</a>
</form>
```

the js call is like this

```
$( "#profileSubmit" ).click(function() {
        $.post("?r=site/addBasicProfile",
                function(data){
                alert(data); // this is alerting as empty
                    if(data==1)
                        window.location.href="?r=site/index";
                });
        });
```

The actual method which is called is

```
public function actionAddBasicProfile(){
    echo $_REQUEST['profile']; 
    // when i echo something static it is reflected in the ajax callback function
 }
```

I'm sure the url is correct and ajax request is passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you don't pass any data to the $.post(), from the jquery website:

```
jQuery.post( url, [data,] [success(data, textStatus, jqXHR),] [dataType] )
```

So you should pass some data to your php script:

```
$.post("?r=site/addBasicProfile",
    $('#registration-form').serialize(), // this will serialize the form data
    function(data){
       alert(data); // this is alerting as empty
       if(data==1)
       window.location.href="?r=site/index";
    }
);
```

And as a side note you should use `$_POST` to get POST values since `$_REQUEST` can also get you the GET values.

Answer (score 0):

or serialize form and also could use lowercase in names.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the form parameters as data with the $.post call.
examples @ http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

You can also use ajaxSubmit available with the JQuery forms plugin, which will handle it for you. @ http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

$('#form').ajaxSubmit({
    success: handle_success,
});